# Run StormCrawler in local mode or install Apache Storm?

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

So I'm trying to figure out how to install and setup Storm/Stormcrawler with ES and Kibana as described [here](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch).

I never installed Storm on my local machine because I've worked with Nutch before and I never had to install Hadoop locally... thought it might be the same with Storm(maybe not?).

I'd like to start crawling with Stormcrawler instead of Nutch now.

It seems that if I just download a release and add the /bin to my PATH, I can **only** talk to a remote cluster.

It seems like I need to setup a development environment according to [this](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Setting-up-development-environment.html), to give me the ability to develop different topologies over time and then just talk to the remote cluster from my local machine when ready to deploy the new topologies. Is that right?

So it seems like all I need to do is add Storm as a dependency to my Stormcrawler project when I build it with Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Getting Started page](http://stormcrawler.net/getting-started/) and the [tutorials on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUuzkdeQV-XEPUq53bH_b5A).

You don't need to install Storm as you can run the topology in local mode, just as you'd do with Nutch and Hadoop. Just generate a topology from the archetype, modify it to your needs e.g. add ES components and run it with -local. See README generated by the archetype.

Later on, you'd install Storm to benefit from the UI and possibly run it on multiple nodes but as a starting point doing it locally is a good way of exploring the capabilities of StormCrawler.

Comment: thanks for the concise answer for a good starting point with this.

Comment: Are you sure there is no need to install storm for local mode? Accourding to storm-crawler document, storm should be installed first: [readme](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources)

Comment: @ArefehTam In order to run Stormcrawler locally you don't need to run storm. However you need to add storm to your env path variables in order to inject and crawl your jar.