# running storm crawler in local mode without the dependency of zookeeper ,nimbus

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I am storing urls in mysql and the indexed data in lucene .I am running storm crawler as applcation server in multiple machines using tomcat. do i actually need zookeeper,nimbus and storm to distribute urls(from mysql) among servers..??

Comment: Hi, please ask one question at a time. You are asking about Storm and buckets at the same time.

Comment: @JulienNioche  I am storing urls in mysql and the indexed data in lucene .I am running storm crawler as applcation server in multiple machines using tomcat. do i actually need zookeeper,nimbus and storm to distribute urls(from mysql) among servers..??  

i

Comment: i want to use storm crawler as library without running storm clusters.. is it possible?                                                                                                                                                                  
As i can have lock and get mechanism to take urls from mysql by applcation servers(to avoid processing same url by multiple application servers ), shall i run without storm dependency??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See FAQ](http://stormcrawler.net/faq/)

> Q: Do I need a Storm cluster to run StormCrawler?
>
> A: No. It can run in local mode and will just use the Storm libraries as dependencies. It makes sense to install Storm in pseudo-distributed mode though so that you can use its UI to monitor the topologies.

See also [Run StormCrawler in local mode or install Apache Storm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994601/run-stormcrawler-in-local-mode-or-install-apache-storm)

Comment: i just used storm jar files for running but it contains nimbus and zookeeper .what is the purpose of those in storm crawler?